R Tidymodels textrecipes - tokenizing with spacyR - how to remove punctuations from produced list of tokens
I would like to tokenize my text by using the step_tokenize with the spacyR engine before proceeding to lemmatisation using step_lemma. Following that, i would like to remove for example punctuations from the list of tokens.
When using the default tokenizers::tokenize_words you can pass this option through a list of options in step_tokenize().
However, my understanding is that step_tokenize uses spacy_parse on the backend which does not provide such an option.
Is there a way to remove for e.g. punctuations or numeric tokens from the tokens produced after lemmatisation using step_lemma()?
A reprex:
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
library(textrecipes)
library(spacyr)

text = "It was a day, Tuesday. It wasn't Thursday!"

df <- tibble(text)

spacyr::spacy_initialize(entity = FALSE)

lexicon_features_tokenized_lemmatised <-
  recipe(~ text, data = df%>%head(1)) %>%
  step_tokenize(text, engine = "spacyr") %>%
  step_lemma(text) %>%
  prep() %>%
  bake(new_data = NULL) 

lexicon_features_tokenized_lemmatised %>% pull(text) %>%textrecipes:::get_tokens()

Output:
"it", "be", "a", "day", ",", "Tuesday", ".", "it", "be", "not", "Thursday", "!"
Desired output (Removal of "!", "," and "."):
"it", "be", "a", "day", "Tuesday", "it", "be", "not", "Thursday"

You want to use the step_pos_filter() to filter the output of spacy by POS.
It is a little annoying, because you have to specify the types to keep. Full list of tags found here https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/glossary.py
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
library(textrecipes)
library(spacyr)

text = "It was a day, Tuesday. It wasn't Thursday!"

df <- tibble(text)

spacyr::spacy_initialize(entity = FALSE)

pos <- c("ADJ", "ADP", "ADV", "AUX", "CONJ", "CCONJ", "DET", "INTJ", "NOUN", 
         "NUM", "PART", "PRON", "PROPN", "SCONJ", "SYM", "VERB", "X", "EOL", 
         "SPACE")

lexicon_features_tokenized_lemmatised <-
  recipe(~ text, data = df %>% head(1)) %>%
  step_tokenize(text, engine = "spacyr") %>%
  step_pos_filter(text, keep_tags = pos) %>%
  step_lemma(text) %>%
  prep() %>%
  bake(new_data = NULL) 

lexicon_features_tokenized_lemmatised %>% 
  pull(text) %>%
  textrecipes:::get_tokens()
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "it"       "be"       "a"        "day"      "Tuesday"  "it"       "be"      
#> [8] "not"      "Thursday"


If you want to remove punctuations you could use the strip_punct option in the step_tokenize function like this:
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
library(textrecipes)
library(spacyr)

text = "It was a day, Tuesday. It wasn't Thursday!"

df <- tibble(text)

spacyr::spacy_initialize(entity = FALSE)
#> successfully initialized (spaCy Version: 3.7.4, language model: en_core_web_sm)

lexicon_features_tokenized_lemmatised <-
  recipe(~ text, data = df%>%head(1)) %>%
  step_tokenize(text, 
                options = list(strip_punct = TRUE)) %>%
  #step_lemma(text) %>%
  prep() %>%
  bake(new_data = NULL) 

lexicon_features_tokenized_lemmatised %>% pull(text) %>% textrecipes:::get_tokens()
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "it"       "was"      "a"        "day"      "tuesday"  "it"       "wasn't"  
#> [8] "thursday"

Created on 2024-04-12 with reprex v2.0.2

Thank you for the answer. However, I want to use spacyr as a tokenizer engine and not the default one so that I can later perform lemmatization.
